# How to install OpenJFX 11

Tags: java, installation, bluej, openjfx

I am trying to install the latest version of BlueJ, and it requires JDK 11 and OpenJFX. I have updated from Java 8 to 11 now, but I cannot find a way to actually install OpenJFX. I've tried to check the version of Open JFX, but I get an error message, and GDebi installer says that the dependancy is not there. No, `sudo apt-get install openjfx` is not working. Could anyone please help?

Output:
`dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bluej: bluej depends on openjfx (>= 11); however: Version of openjfx on system is 8u60-b27-4.`

Comment: See [How to install openjfx along with openjdk-11?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1036098) on https://askubuntu.com

Comment: https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your openjfx is in older version, version for Java 8. You can either:

- purge old installation and install openjfx-11,
- download archive from openjfx website, extract it and link your projects to extracted directory.

Maybe there is an option to force installation of openjfx-11 but I prefer to purge old files first. Otherwise you may have a "little mess" later on.